# Password protected chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I made a chrome extension which runs successfully and does the job for which it was intended for.
I need to make the extension password protected and someone can use the application only with their Gmail user and password.

I have experience using google authentication using google APIs client library and can implement it in my application. But in that case, all google users can run the application. I thought about storing some file where will list all allowed users emails. However, chrome extensions are open to edit so anyone who has a little experience with extension development can find and edit that file.

Are there any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered to build a web api and move some logic to remote server? Then you could make rules in the server and determine who can access the functionalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code that runs on an extension on *my* machine is my code, not yours. I can control anything and everything about the execution of the extension, including altering the code on disk and reloading the extension in chrome.

I can break any and all protections and defences you place in a pretty trivial matter. And I'm also pretty proficient with deobfuscating jumbled code, so don't think about going that way.

Keep authentication logic on the server, more generally, keep *anything that needs absolute control* on the server. You don't really care if I mess with your extension and see a red background instead of blue, you do care if I can access things I shouldn't.